# Proof that b is not divisible by 6

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

$$b=\left \lfloor (\sqrt[3]{28}-3)^{-n} \right \rfloor$$

The brackets mean that the number is the largest integer smaller than $(\sqrt[3]{28}-3)^{-n} $

Proof that b is never divisible by 6.

I have no idea how to even start, I thought to do it by induction, but that didn't even remotely work :(

Anybody keen to help out

Comment: You claim this is [tag:contest-math]. Source?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: I claim

$$ (\sqrt[3]{28} - 3)^{-n} + (\omega \sqrt[3]{28} - 3)^{-n} + (\omega^2 \sqrt[3]{28} - 3)^{-n} $$

is an integer, where $\omega$ is a primitive cube root of unity.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $3=\sqrt[3]{27}$, so $\sqrt[3]{28}-3=\frac{28-27}{\sqrt[3]{28^2}+\sqrt[3]{28\cdot 27}+\sqrt[3]{27^2}}$, so we are looking at $\left\lfloor \left( \sqrt[3]{28^2}+\sqrt[3]{28\cdot 27}+\sqrt[3]{27^2}\right)^n\right \rfloor$  Now experimentation says the number inside the floor is just a tiny bit less than a multiple of $3$ for $n \gt 1$.  Usually this would be proved by finding a $c$ such that $\left( \sqrt[3]{28^2}+\sqrt[3]{28\cdot 27}+\sqrt[3]{27^2}\right)^n + c^n$ is an integer and a  multiple of $3$ and $|c| \lt 1$

Comment: Shouldn't it be ${\color{red}+}\sqrt[3]{28\cdot 27}$?

Comment: @PabloRotondo:  yes, it should.  Thanks